# Why is my isdigit() function returning the ascii code instead of the int, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: c++

The following code snippet is supposed to run through a vector of strings (words), and if the string contains an integer, it should push the int to an integer vector (nums) that contains only those numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < words.at(i).size(); j++){
        if (isdigit(words[i][j])){
            nums.push_back(words[i][j]);
        }
    }
    cout << words.at(i) << endl;
}
```

I've been given a file with the words on it. My code successfully pulls the words from the file and places them in a vector. However, my isdigit() function is not returning the expected values. The words are ho1d
h4m,
dance2,
8est,
next,
di6est,
se3d,
tes7 and my expected value for the nums vector is 1,4,2,8,6,3,7. Here's my print snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        cout << nums.at(i) << " ";
    }
```

But it's returning the values 49 52 50 56 54 51 55. EDIT: Just recognized that these are the ascii values. How do I prevent them from pushing the ascii values instead of the integers? I've even tried to use the get() function and run through every character instead of every line while reading the input, and I still get the same values returned. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Look at those numbers.  Do you see a pattern in how to convert those numbers to integers (even though ASCII values are integers)?  Does the number `48` or character `'0'` come to mind?

Comment: There is a difference between the numerical values 0 to 9 and the characters `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do if it finds two or more digits? Are they treated separately or as one larger integer?

Answer (score 4):

When you add the `words[i][j]` to the `nums` vector, you can do this:

```
nums.push_back(words[i][j] - '0');
```

**Explanation**: Since the first digit in the ASCII table is `'0'`, you can subtract it from other digits (as `char` values) in order to get the difference as a number.

Here is a full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "ho1d", "h4m", "dance2", "8est", "next", "di6est", "se3d", "tes7"};
    std::vector<int> nums;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < words.at(i).size(); j++){
            if (isdigit(words[i][j])){
                nums.push_back(words[i][j] - '0');
            }
        }
        std::cout << words.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        std::cout << nums.at(i) << " ";
    }
}
```

This code prints:

```
ho1d
h4m
dance2
8est
next
di6est
se3d
tes7
1 4 2 8 6 3 7
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Could you explained why that worked?

Comment: I have edited the post and added an explanation. Basically, the `0` char has code `48` and the other digits are `'1'=49`, `'2'=50`, `'3'=51`, etc. So if you substract, let's say, `'4'` (code=`52`) from `'0'`, the result is `4` (since `52 - 48 = 4`) as you wanted.

Comment: It's not just ASCII. It's required by the language definition, regardless of the character encoding. The values of `'0'` through `'9'` are required to be contiguous and increasing, so `ch - '0'` always works when `ch` holds any of the characters `'0'..'9'`.

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of atoi() like below:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < words.at(i).size(); j++)
    {
        if (isdigit(words[i][j]))
        {
            char c = words[i][j];
            nums.push_back(atoi(&c));
        }
    }
    std::cout << words.at(i) << std::endl;
  }
```

for C++ you can  use `stoi` stl function

Comment: Note `atoi` as used here will attempt to read multiple consecutive digits. For example, if the input contained `b10ck`, this would get the number `10` then the number `0` (where the original code would get the number `1` then the number `0`).

Comment: `atoi` is completely unnecessary here. For a single digit, just subtract `'0'`.

Comment: @aschepler: Modified code to cover the scenario that you mentioned

Comment: That change is no good, because now `&c` is not a null-terminated string. Really, just use `words[i][j] - '0'`.  C++ does guarantee `isdigit` will only return truthy for the ten ordinary digit characters regardless of locale, and that those ten digit characters have consecutive numeric values, even if those values are not consistent with ASCII.